# Как сделать фильтрацию в связи многие ко многим?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, many-to-many

Пытаюсь узнать, как отфильтровать данные.
Имеются три таблицы (многие ко многим). Игры, категории и связующая.

Следующий код выводит только одну игру по id

```
public IActionResult Main(string categoryN)
      {
         int CurrCategoryID = 2;
         string _categoryN = "Action";
                 var games = _context.Games.Include(x => x.Categories)
                     .Where(x => x.ID == CurrCategoryID)
                     .ToList();
                 return View(games);   }
```

Но как сделать вывод Игр по id определенной категории?

Comment: Ваш вопрос не связан напрямую с asp.net-mvc, поэтому удалите эту метку. И добавьте метку EF или EF Core.

Answer (score 0):

```
var games = _context.Games.Where(x => x.Categories.Any(y => y.ID == 1)).ToList();
                return View(games);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]